# Optimization with scipy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

in the following code I want to optimize(maximize power output) a wind farm using scipy optimize. the variable in each iteration is c, which c=0 shows the wind turbine is off and c=1 shows, it is running. so in each iteration, I want to change C values and get the power output. the problem is that the initial guess which is x0 and indeed is c remains the same at each iteration and will not update. so optimization is not useful and does not work since c remains the same. now I want to know how can I solve this problem? I have put some print to show that how c and power output(function must be optimized) will not change.I mean I put any c values as initial guess(x0) will give a power output which will not change neither c, nor power output.
import time

```
from py_wake.examples.data.hornsrev1 import V80 
from py_wake.examples.data.hornsrev1 import Hornsrev1Site # We work with the Horns Rev 1 site, which comes already set up with PyWake.
from py_wake import BastankhahGaussian
from py_wake.turbulence_models import GCLTurbulence
from py_wake.deflection_models.jimenez import JimenezWakeDeflection
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from py_wake.wind_turbines.power_ct_functions import PowerCtFunctionList, PowerCtTabular
import numpy as np

def newSite(x,y):
    xNew=np.array([x[0]+560*i for i in range(4)])
    yNew=np.array([y[0]+560*i for i in range(4)])    
    x_newsite=np.array([xNew[0],xNew[0],xNew[0],xNew[1]])
    y_newsite=np.array([yNew[0],yNew[1],yNew[2],yNew[0]])

    return (x_newsite,y_newsite)



def wt_simulation(c):
    
    c = c.reshape(4,360,23)
    site = Hornsrev1Site()
    x, y = site.initial_position.T
    x_newsite,y_newsite=newSite(x,y)
    windTurbines = V80()
    
    
    for item in range(4):
        for j in range(10,370,10):
            for i in range(j-10,j):
                c[item][i]=c[item][j-5]
          
    windTurbines.powerCtFunction = PowerCtFunctionList(
    key='operating',
    powerCtFunction_lst=[PowerCtTabular(ws=[0, 100], power=[0, 0], power_unit='w', ct=[0, 0]), # 0=No power and ct
                         windTurbines.powerCtFunction], # 1=Normal operation
    default_value=1)

    operating = np.ones((4,360,23)) # shape=(#wt,wd,ws)
    operating[c <= 0.5]=0
    
    wf_model = BastankhahGaussian(site, windTurbines,deflectionModel=JimenezWakeDeflection(),turbulenceModel=GCLTurbulence())

    # run wind farm simulation
    sim_res = wf_model(
        x_newsite, y_newsite, # wind turbine positions
        h=None, # wind turbine heights (defaults to the heights defined in windTurbines)
        wd=None, # Wind direction (defaults to site.default_wd (0,1,...,360 if not overriden))
        ws=None, # Wind speed (defaults to site.default_ws (3,4,...,25m/s if not overriden))
        operating=operating
   )
    

    print(-float(np.sum(sim_res.Power)))
    return -float(np.sum(sim_res.Power))  # negative because of scipy minimize
         
t0 = time.perf_counter()

        
def solve():
    
    wt =4  # for V80  
    wd=360
    ws=23
    x0 = np.ones((wt,wd,ws)).reshape(-1)  # initial value for c
    b=(0,1)
    bounds=np.full((wt,wd,ws,2),b).reshape(-1, 2)

    
    res = minimize(wt_simulation, x0=x0, bounds=bounds)

    return res
    
res=solve()

print(f'success status: {res.success}')
print(f'aep: {-res.fun}')  # negative to get the true maximum aep
print(f'c values: {res.x}\n')
print(f'elapse: {round(time.perf_counter() - t0)}s')  

sim_res=wt_simulation(res.x)
```

Comment: It looks like a vanishing gradient problem. Do you know what the objective function looks like? By the way, your domain is a a box (read from your bounds) and you are starting from one of its edge. Wouldn't you prefer starting from the midpoint `x0 = np.full((wt,wd,ws), 0.5).reshape(-1)` instead?

Comment: The objective function is the summation of power outputs. each wind turbine(`wt`) at each wind direction(`wd`) and wind speed(`ws`) produces power , so they must be summed and find the final power output.  so  `sim_res.Power`  is the power that is a function of `[wt][wd][ws]`. regarding the offered x0 by you, the result remain the same and c will not change